# Some Twitter Videos are not exposed by the API

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-rest-api

I noticed that *in some cases*, the video attached with the tweet is not accessible by using the REST API.

For example, [this tweet clearly has video](https://twitter.com/ufc/status/901671478671769600) in it. however, this video is nowhere to be found when the tweet is retrieved from the API as shown below.

Is there an explanation for this?

**Response from `statuses/show` with `include_entities` set to `true`:**

```
{
   "created_at":"Sun Aug 27 05:03:27 +0000 2017",
   "id":901671478671769600,
   "id_str":"901671478671769600",
   "text":"\"I thought it was close. He's very composed. Fair play to @FloydMayweather.\" #ConorMcGregor @TheNotoriousMMA\u2026 https:\/\/t.co\/GqaK2rfCc8",
   "truncated":true,
   "entities":{
      "hashtags":[
         {
            "text":"ConorMcGregor",
            "indices":[
               77,
               91
            ]
         }
      ],
      "symbols":[

      ],
      "user_mentions":[
         {
            "screen_name":"FloydMayweather",
            "name":"Floyd Mayweather",
            "id":42519612,
            "id_str":"42519612",
            "indices":[
               58,
               74
            ]
         },
         {
            "screen_name":"TheNotoriousMMA",
            "name":"Conor McGregor",
            "id":369583954,
            "id_str":"369583954",
            "indices":[
               92,
               108
            ]
         }
      ],
      "urls":[
         {
            "url":"https:\/\/t.co\/GqaK2rfCc8",
            "expanded_url":"https:\/\/twitter.com\/i\/web\/status\/901671478671769600",
            "display_url":"twitter.com\/i\/web\/status\/9\u2026",
            "indices":[
               110,
               133
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   "source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/snappytv.com\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eSnappyTV.com\u003c\/a\u003e",
   "in_reply_to_status_id":null,
   "in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,
   "in_reply_to_user_id":null,
   "in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,
   "in_reply_to_screen_name":null,
   "user":{
      "id":6446742,
      "id_str":"6446742",
      "name":"UFC",
      "screen_name":"ufc",
      "location":"Worldwide",
      "description":"#MayweatherMcGregor | Sat. August 26 | LIVE on https:\/\/t.co\/Crf9DpHU3k",
      "url":"https:\/\/t.co\/a7DrIfLzyv",
      "entities":{
         "url":{
            "urls":[
               {
                  "url":"https:\/\/t.co\/a7DrIfLzyv",
                  "expanded_url":"http:\/\/bit.ly\/2oaqFfb",
                  "display_url":"bit.ly\/2oaqFfb",
                  "indices":[
                     0,
                     23
                  ]
               }
            ]
         },
         "description":{
            "urls":[
               {
                  "url":"https:\/\/t.co\/Crf9DpHU3k",
                  "expanded_url":"http:\/\/ufc.com\/order",
                  "display_url":"ufc.com\/order",
                  "indices":[
                     47,
                     70
                  ]
               }
            ]
         }
      },
      "protected":false,
      "followers_count":6157894,
      "friends_count":21053,
      "listed_count":13522,
      "created_at":"Wed May 30 16:11:00 +0000 2007",
      "favourites_count":17241,
      "utc_offset":-25200,
      "time_zone":"Pacific Time (US & Canada)",
      "geo_enabled":true,
      "verified":true,
      "statuses_count":80210,
      "lang":"en",
      "contributors_enabled":false,
      "is_translator":false,
      "is_translation_enabled":false,
      "profile_background_color":"000000",
      "profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/718558259867570176\/KrPdz61x.jpg",
      "profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/718558259867570176\/KrPdz61x.jpg",
      "profile_background_tile":false,
      "profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/622297337839288320\/h8h5fjmf_normal.png",
      "profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/622297337839288320\/h8h5fjmf_normal.png",
      "profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/6446742\/1503859206",
      "profile_link_color":"D91111",
      "profile_sidebar_border_color":"000000",
      "profile_sidebar_fill_color":"FAF5F5",
      "profile_text_color":"0F0F0F",
      "profile_use_background_image":true,
      "has_extended_profile":false,
      "default_profile":false,
      "default_profile_image":false,
      "following":false,
      "follow_request_sent":false,
      "notifications":false,
      "translator_type":"regular"
   },
   "geo":null,
   "coordinates":null,
   "place":null,
   "contributors":null,
   "is_quote_status":false,
   "retweet_count":4637,
   "favorite_count":10033,
   "favorited":false,
   "retweeted":false,
   "possibly_sensitive":false,
   "possibly_sensitive_appealable":false,
   "lang":"en"
}
```

Comment: Do you have a programming question? This seem like it should be aimed at Twitter support.

Comment: Add `tweet_mode=extended` to the url, this will then return a media_id, which you can then query the media api endpoint.

Comment: LInk related to Lawrence's comment: https://twittercommunity.com/t/some-video-tweets-not-showing-extended-entities/75788

Comment: Thanks @LawrenceCherone. This parameter is what I needed.